# CK Editor does not format newline characters like \n

Tags: c#, ckeditor

I am using CK Editor to display some string with html formatting like bold. I have created this string in C# and displaying in CKEditor. PFB my code

```
string abc = "<div><h1>Test Text</h1>abcd \n efgh\n <b>ijkl</b> </div>";
this.CKEditor2.Text = abc;
```

In my CKEditor it displays as follows
Test Text
abcdefgh**ijkl**

It clearly doesn't allow \n as  line breaks. I am trying to set up the custom linebreaks for my CKEditor. I am not sure why its not working. PFB my config.js file for the CKEditor.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.removePlugins = 'toolbar,elementspath,resize';
config.allowedContent = true;
config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlWriter();

// The character sequence to use for every indentation step.
writer.indentationChars = '\t';

// The way to close self closing tags, like <br />.
writer.selfClosingEnd = ' />';

// The character sequence to be used for line breaks.
writer.lineBreakChars = '\n';
```

};

Any inputs on this one please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using html, why not just make

```
string abc = "<div><h1>Test Text</h1>abcd </br> efgh</br> <b>ijkl</b> </div>";
```

and replace \t with either `&nbsp;`, `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;`, or `&emsp`;

You could also use the `<pre>` when displaying pre-formatted text, which preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Ideally with tabs if you can use CSS `padding-left:5em` or `margin-left:5em` that would be ideal.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, its one of the last Option but that will be a workaround for this   problem. I am thinking that I am missing some configuration setting in config.js that we can leverage for this as CKEditor is highly customizable. So, far not much help available..Please comment if you are aware of any...Any Javascript Experts please chime in

Comment: you might want to change "writer.indentationChars" to "writer.dataIndentationChars" though "\t" is the default if not set. see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-dataIndentationChars and for line breaks, see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlWriter-method-lineBreak

Comment: I am using CKEDITOR.htmlwriter() in my example. but thats throwing an error saying that the CKEDITOR not found or htmlwriter() not found or supported by CKEDITOR element .Sometimes it does nothing and no change in the output for CKEDITOR. BTW I am using CKEDITOR 3.6.6.2 for ASP.NET. The doubt the settings you pointed will work for 3.x

Comment: The slash is at the end of self closing tags, it's <br/> if you insist on closing them, but <br> will do.